# Error al querer editar registros de un formulario junto con imagen

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

Estoy generando un formulario con Vue, Laravel y Axios donde además de datos como nombre y DNI, cargo una foto por cada uno de los usuarios, a la hora de cargar la imagen no tengo problemas, pero al momento de querer modificar cualquiera de los otros campos o la foto inclusive, se va por el catch.

Este es mi código en el componente

```
actualizaPersona(){
               if (this.validarPersona()){
                    return;
                }
                
                let me = this;
                
                let formData = new FormData();
                
                formData.append('nombre', this.nombre);
                formData.append('tipo_documento', this.tipo_documento)
                formData.append("num_documento", this.num_documento);
                formData.append("direccion", this.direccion);
                formData.append("telefono", this.telefono);
                formData.append("email", this.email);
                formData.append("foto_dni", this.foto_dni);
                formData.append("persona_id", this.persona_id);
                //formData.append('_method', 'PUT');

                axios.put('/cliente/actualizar',formData,{
                    
                     headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
                }).then(function (response) {
                    me.cerrarModal();
                    me.listarPersona();
                }).catch(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    
                }); 
            },
```

Este es mi código en el controlador

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
        
        $persona = Persona::findOrFail($request->id);
        $entrada=$request->all();
      

        $fotoactual= $persona->foto_dni;
        if($request->hasFile('foto_dni')){
            
            if($fotoactual != 'error.png'){
                Storage::delete('fotosdni'.$persona->foto_dni);
            }
            return("aca 3");
            $nombreFoto = $request->num_documento;

                $archivo=$request->file('foto_dni');
                $nombre=$nombreFoto.'.'.$archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $archivo->move('fotosdni', $nombre);
                $entrada['foto_dni']=$nombre;
                
        }else{

            $entrada['foto_dni']=$persona->foto_dni;
            
        }

        $persona->nombre = $entrada['nombre'];
        $persona->tipo_documento = $entrada['tipo_documento'];
        $persona->num_documento = $entrada['num_documento'];
        $persona->direccion = $entrada['direccion'];
        $persona->telefono = $entrada['telefono'];
        $persona->email = $entrada['email'];
        $persona->foto_dni = $entrada['foto_dni'];
        
        
        $persona->save();
        
    }
```

Y mi ruta es la siguiente

```
Route::put('/cliente/actualizar', 'ClienteController@update');
```

El error es el siguiente

[image: ERROR]

no puedo siquiera comprobar si mi funcion update funciona ya que el problema parece ser con las rutas.

También probé de la siguiente manera

```
axios.put('/cliente/actualizar',formData,{
                    
                     headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
                }).then(function (response) {
                    me.cerrarModal();
                    me.listarPersona();
                }).catch(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    
                });
```

Y también usando la **linea formData.append('_method', 'PUT');**

Comment: Suena tonto, pero estás pasando la ruta `actualizar32` pero tu ruta lo espera de la siguiente forma: `actualizar` **/** `32`, en este caso el slash determina que tipo de endpoint irá. La respuesta es correcta, tu endpoint no existe y por eso entra al catch

Comment: Si, pasa que me olvié de actualizar el error, perdon, error mio entre tantas veces que modifiqué el codigo, ahora actualizo las imagenes

Comment: Ok, veo que editaste. Vuelvo a lo mismo: tu ruta en Laravel espera un parámetro de la siguente manera `path/route/{param}`, si solos haces: `path/route` o `path/route{param}` te devolverá un error 404 , y eso está bien.

Comment: ok, revisaré eso, muchas gracias por comentar y ayudar :)

Comment: No es nada. Dejas saber cualquier cosa que te suceda.

Comment: tienes la ruta metida dentro de un group, el 404 es que el recurso no se encontro pero no es nada de logica

Comment: Probablemente tengas problemas con el codificado `multipart/form-data` y los métodos PUT/PATCH. Pero antes de pasar a eso, asegúrate de que la url sea la correcta, puedes probarlo quitando el header en axios  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" y enviando el request sin el archivo. Luego dale una leída a este hilo https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457#issuecomment-239451567

Answer (score 1):

El error es que no consigue la ruta solicitada.

Al escribir '/cliente/actualizar' le estas diciendo a axios que tome como base la ruta de tu servidor de Vue.js, pero tiene que pasarle la ruta de tu servidor de Laravel, es decir, donde esta corriendo tu API.

Suponiendo que estas trabajando bajo el dominio localhost haz lo siguiente:

```
axios.put('http://localhost:80/cliente/actualizar',formData ...
```

O si tu controlador esta declarado en el archivo api.php

```
axios.put('http://localhost:80/api/cliente/actualizar',formData ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Existen problemas al utilizar métodos PUT con multipart en Laravel. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457

La solución más sencilla es cambiar a un método POST y realizar el mismo proceso.

Esta es la solución propuesta en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686218/laravel-vuejs-axios-put-request-formdata-is-empty

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/304892)